# Visually attach Scrollbar to Listbox: TkInter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having an issue with a TkInter interface whereby I cannot get a scrollbar to visually attach itself to a Listbox element - see this image: [Problem interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd4h0.png)

Here is the code which creates and positions the Listbox & Scrollbar:

```
        lblpd3 = ttk.Label(mainframe,text='',font=("Helvetica", 5))
        lblpd3.grid(column=0, row=12, sticky=NW)
        scltrn = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient=VERTICAL)
        lbltrn = ttk.Label(mainframe,text='Select Transformation',font=("Helvetica", 11, "bold"))
        lbltrn.grid(column=0, row=13, sticky=NW)     
        self.lsttrn = Listbox(mainframe,selectmode=SINGLE,exportselection=0,width=62,height=4,yscrollcommand=scltrn.set,activestyle='none',selectbackground='#4A6984',selectborderwidth=3,highlightcolor='#4A6984',highlightthickness=1)
        scltrn.config(command=self.lsttrn.yview)
        scltrn.grid(column=0, row=14, sticky=(N,S,E)) 
        for item in self.coord:
            self.lsttrn.insert(END, item)
        self.lsttrn.grid(column=0, row=14, padx=0, sticky=NW)
        self.lsttrn.select_set(0)
```

Is there a simple hack I could use to push the scrollbar a few pixels to the left - documentation seems to suggest there's no padding element?

Comment: are you calling `mainframe.grid_columnconfigure` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @BryanOakley this is about as close:             
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Comment: I don't understand what "this is about as close" -- are you saying you _are_ calling it? Also, you are putting both scrltrn` and `self.lsttrn` in column 0, row 14. Is that intentional?

Comment: @BryanOakley what i meant by saying "this is about as close" is I've not called the 'mainframe.grid_columnconfigure' function but i have called 'mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S)) mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)'. Yes that is intentional as my second column contains buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your `Scrollbar` widget and your `Listbox` widget into their own seperate `Frame`.

Then add that in as a single 'unit'.

While I dont know your whole program, here's what the logic behind the fix should roughly look like:

```
# Declare a new Frame to hold your Listbox and Scroll wheel    
myFrame = Frame.__init__(self, parent) 

# Make sure your Scrollbar is a part of our newly created Frame "myFrame"
scltrn = Scrollbar(myframe, orient=VERTICAL)

# Make sure your Listbox is a part of our newly created Frame "myFrame"
self.lsttrn = Listbox(myFrame,selectmode=SINGLE,exportselection=0,width=62,height=4,yscrollcommand=scltrn.set,activestyle='none',selectbackground='#4A6984',selectborderwidth=3,highlightcolor='#4A6984',highlightthickness=1)

...

#pack the Scrollbar and Listbox together in our Frame IN THIS ORDER
self.lsttrn.pack()
scltrn.pack()

....
# Now grid our Frame containing both the Scrollwheel and Listbox to your GUI
myFrame.grid(column=xxx,row=xxx,padx=xxx,sticky=xxx)
```

This shouldnt be a copy+paste fix, but hopefully you understand the logic behind creating a `Frame` to hold your Scrollbar and Listbox, and then gridding **that** in, rather than both seperately.

Hope this helps! ~Gunner

Comment: With some modifications I was able to get this to work perfectly, it was the 'Frame' that I needed. Thank you as well to @BryanOakley for the help

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem stems from the fact that you are putting the scrollbar and listbox in the same column. They need to be in different columns.

One really simple solution is to use a frame that contains *only* the listbox and scrollbar. Because you don't have a horizontal scrollbar you can use `pack` to put the listbox and scrollbar in the frame with just a couple lines of code. You can then place that frame in a single column in its parent.